# Replace Least significant bit of double dimension array with other bit of single dimension

Tags: java

I am trying to replace least significant bits of rgb from result arrays's bits

```
for (int k = 0; k < rgb.length ; ++k)
{       
    for (int n=0; n<rgb[k].length; n++) 
    {               
        rgb[k][n] = (rgb[k][n] >> 1) << 1;  
        rgb[k][n] = rgb[k][n] | result[n];       
    }
}
```

rgb is double dimension array and result is single dimension array, 
rgb is having values like 
10010110
11000110
10101010
where as result array is having 
0
1
1...

but i m not getting appropriate output..

Comment: Is an attempt at steganography what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: There's a better way to reset the least significant bit than shifting back and forth (x&~1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are trying to do

```
int[][] rgb = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
int[] result = {0, 1};

for (int[] arr : rgb)
    for (int n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
        arr[n] = result[n] == 0 ?
                 (arr[n] & ~1) /* clear */ : 
                 (arr[n] | 1) /* set */;


for (int[] arr : rgb) {
    String sep = "";
    for(int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(sep + Integer.toBinaryString(i));    
        sep = ", ";
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
0, 11
10, 101
```

Comment: thanx buddy, Arrays class is not having toBinaryString() method so ho could i convert it in binary..

Comment: You need to use another loop.

Comment: this code is working but it is replacing all values by only top 3 values of other array,it is not using other values

Comment: actually 1st array is double dimensional, each row consists 3 values 
so i think so, after replacing elements of 1st row it again starts from 0th element of 2nd array